# Does $x^p=x$ for any finite field with characteristic $p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, finite-groups

I know it's true when the field has $p$ elements (an easy application of Lagranges theorem to the group of units), but how about when the field has $p^k$ elements?

Comment: Remember that over a field, a polynomial equation can have at most as many roots as the degree of the polynomial!  However something fairly similar is true.

Comment: Not true. Take $\mathbb{F}_4\cong \mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2+x+1)$. Then $\bar{x}^2=x+1\neq x$.

Comment: Every field of characteristic $p$ is a vector space over the "base field" $\Bbb F_p = \Bbb Z/p$. The equation $x^p=x$ holds precisely for the $p$ elements of the base field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Counterexample given in comments by David Hill)
(Remark given in comments by Ted Shifrin)

Consider $\bar{x} \in \Bbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2+x+1) \cong \Bbb{F}_4$. Then $\overline{x}^2 = \overline{x+1} \neq \overline{x}$

As a remark, any $x \in \Bbb{F}_{p^k}\backslash \Bbb{F}_p$ will be a counterexample. To see this, notice that the polynomial $x^p-x$ will have at most $p$ distinct roots, but all of the elements of $\Bbb{F}_p$ are roots of it. So they are the only roots.

However, you can get a result that says that if $\text{char}(\Bbb{F})=p$, then for any $x,y \in \Bbb{F}$, $(x+y)^p = x^p+y^p$.

Comment: Nice example ...

Comment: I said that it was given in the comments

Comment: It might be good to mention another point, given in another comment, that **any** element of $\mathbb F_{p^k}$ that isn't in $\mathbb F_p$ is a counterexample. So any "reasonable" attempt to produce a counterexample will succeed.